# Integral inside sum gives index label error

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy

Here's something I'm trying out based on this page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSineSeries.aspx

```
from sympy import *
f = Function('f')
B = IndexedBase('B')
x, L = symbols('x L', real=True)
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
n = Idx(n, (0, oo))
Bn = Indexed('B', n)
m = Symbol('m', integer=True)
expr = sin(m*pi*x/L)
lhs = integrate(f(x)*expr, (x,-L,L))
rhs = Sum(Bn*integrate(expr*sin(n*pi*x/L), (x,-L,L)), n)
```

It crashes on the last line, stating that:

```
TypeError: Idx object requires an integer label.
```

The Idx object does, however, have an explicitly set integer label. Furthermore, an expression as `Sum(Bn*sin(n*pi*x/L),n)` works with no problems.

Is the fact that I am putting an integral inside the sum problematic? Or is it just a minor syntax problem?

Comment: I havent used sympy but could this be because `n` stands for both the `Symbol` and `Idx` objects?
`n = Symbol('n', integer=True)`
`n = Idx(n, (0, oo))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the variable `n` is used both as a `Symbol` and a `Idx` object. The following code does not throw an error. (Though I am not sure if it serves your purpose)

```
from sympy import *
f = Function('f')
B = IndexedBase('B')
x, L = symbols('x L', real=True)
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
n_index = Idx(n, (0, oo))
Bn = Indexed('B', n)
m = Symbol('m', integer=True)
expr = sin(m*pi*x/L)
lhs = integrate(f(x)*expr, (x,-L,L))
rhs = Sum(Bn*integrate(expr*sin(n*pi*x/L), (x,-L,L)), n_index)
```

Comment: Indeed, I have realized that the integrand requires a symbol and not Idx object. The resulting expression is not sufficiently simplified. The original link shows that the result of the sum should be $B_m L$. Is there any way I can get that? Since the goal is to be able to symbolically work out $B_m$.

Comment: For instance `Sum(Bn*integrate(expr*sin(n*pi*x/L), (x,-L,L)), (n,0,10)).subs(m,4).doit()` will return a simplified sum.

Comment: I wasnt able to find a solution yet. Just a quick question: would this be useful to solve your problem? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/fourier.html

Comment: The idea behind that method `fourier_series` is that you provide a function `f(x)` and get back a fourier expansion. What I am after is a generic representation of the fourier coefficients ($B_n$) given that I already have a fourier expansion, but don't  know the function it originated from...

Comment: @user32882 ohh.... I'm still not sure how to simplify this. I tried `simplify` but that didnt help either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191057/discussion-between-raghav710-and-user32882).

Comment: @user32882 did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. I accepted your answer because you have answered my question, but it doesn't fix the underlying problem.